# global_navtree is not defined on dutch page but is on other languages

Tags: javascript, undefined, global, nav

I have limited knowledge (like it's not my job) of HTML and no knowledge of JS.
I edit a website that was built years ago by somebody we hired but that person can't edit the website anymore, that's why I do it now.

I think I accidentally changed something in JS and now the navigation bar on top of the page is gone.

This is the website:
http://www.myriammatthee.com/Nederlands/

This is the English version where the navigation bar is still visible:
http://www.myriammatthee.com/Engels/

I can't find what I did wrong!

Answer (score 0):

in `global_navtree.js` file the first line is

```
bvar global_navtree = WpNavBar.readTree({
```

you accidentally added a `b` in front of var, just remove it:

```
var global_navtree = WpNavBar.readTree({
```

Comment: Okay so I removed the "b" but it still hasn't changed.

Comment: sir(or ma'am), the menu is working :)  : http://www.myriammatthee.com/Nederlands/